# How do you get what field is violated on an EntityExistsException?

Tags: java, validation, jpa, openjpa

I have a @UniqueConstraint and @Column(unique=true) annotations on a field.

```
@Table( name = "my_table", 
uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint( columnNames = "name" ) } )

@Column(unique=true)
private String name;
```

When I violate the unique constraint, I get an EntityExistsException. It doesn't look like this class has any way to get what field was null without parsing through a few layers of exceptions and subsequently parsing exception messages.

Is there a non-implementation specific way of get which field was violated, and maybe which record it clashes with for uniqueness? For reference I'm on OpenJpa 2.4.1 and Oracle (but I am looking for a non-implementation specific solution).

Thanks.

Comment: since EntityExistsException has no content other than a message and a cause then there will be no implementation-independent way, since they will all put whatever message they want and provide whatever cause they want. And add to that, each database will have its own cause exception that will differ from what other databases do. Good thing these standards aren't they?

Comment: Dang, I thought as much. Thanks for the tip.